# svc system filesystem root default failed to mount usr

Tags: solaris

I encountered the following error when trying to startup my solaris vm
Can anyone advise how to resolve the issue?

svc system filesystem root default failed to mount usr

system filesystem root default failed fatally: transitioned to maintenance

Can i just reference to this article: http://www.itworld.com/nlsunix070424 or there are other easier ways?

Comment: The error message should contain an instruction such as `see 'svcs -xv' for details`. Please paste the exact error message and the result of following any instructions. Also, please provide the output of `df -hl` and `cat /etc/vfstab`.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to start is the svc log file as reported in the output of "svcs -xv" run after you've logged in at the maintenance prompt you'll be presented.

This log file will often include details of why the svc failed to start and in the case of the filesystem/user filesystem, is commonly caused by a problem with the /etc/vfstab or one of the filesystems or devices referenced within it.